# sql syntax error on insert data with checking in maria db 10?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I run it in my own xampp correctly but when I run it in server it gives me error

```
INSERT INTO `likes`(`id`, `PID`, `UID`)
SELECT NULL,155,68
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM likes t2 WHERE t2.PID = 115 AND t2.UID=68)
```

The error is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM likes t2 WHERE t2.PID = 115 AND
>   t2.UID=68)' at line 3

Please help

Comment: `115` ? `155` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SELECT` requires a `FROM` if it also has `WHERE`.  You can use `FROM dual` if you really want.

However, you are trying to prevent duplicates, and this is not the best way to do that.  Instead, let the database do the work with a unique index or constraint:

```
alter table likes add constraint unq_likes_pid_uid unique (pid, uid);
```

Then, you can express what you want to do as:

```
INSERT INTO `likes`(`PID`, `UID`)
    VALUES (155, 68)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pid = VALUES(pid);
```

The `on duplicate key` actually does nothing except prevent an error.

Why is this better?

- The database guarantees the integrity of the data, so you know it is correct.
- Multiple threads inserting the same values will not "accidentally" insert duplicates.
- There is no need to repeat the constant values in the query, which can introduce errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your scope is to insert new values:

```
INSERT INTO `likes`(`id`, `PID`, `UID`)
values (NULL,155,68)
```

If your scope is to update already existing tuples:

```
 update likes
  set `id`=NULL, `PID`=155, `UID`=68
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM likes t2 WHERE t2.PID = 115 AND t2.UID=68);
```

if your scope is to add a tuple if not present:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure ins_m()
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM likes t2 WHERE t2.PID = 115 AND t2.UID=68)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO `likes`(`id`, `PID`, `UID`)
       values (NULL,155,68)
   END IF
END
$$
delimiter ;

-- to execute the procedure
exec ins_m
```

Your question wasn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
INSERT INTO `likes`(`id`, `PID`, `UID`)
SELECT NULL,155,68 from likes
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM likes t2 WHERE t2.PID = 115 AND t2.UID=68)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM likes t2 WHERE t2.PID = 115 AND t2.UID=68)
INSERT INTO `likes`(`id`, `PID`, `UID`)
values (NULL,155,68)
```